# Extjs 4 Popup window vertical scroll-bar not moving in Google chrome

Tags: popup, scroll, extjs4, tabpanel

I have a popup window in Extjs viewport layout and with in this popup I have a tab panel. When the tabpanel content too large popup window shows vertical scroll bar but the scroll bar not moving in Google chrome browser. It's working fine in Firefox.

[image]

Sample code

```
var first_tab_form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    autoHeight: true,
    frame: false,
    fileUpload: true,
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelWidth: 130,
        labelSeparator: ' ',
        labelAlign: 'right',
        cls: 'textlineht ff_styles'
    },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Field1',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '60%'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Field2 ',
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
         anchor: '90%'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Field3',
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
        anchor: '90%'
        }] 
});

var MyTabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
    activeTab: 0,
    width: 780,
    height: 520,
    //autoHeight: true,
    //minHeight: 600,
    plain: true,
    defaults: {
        autoScroll: true,
        width: 780,
        height: 520,
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'My First Tab',
        //layout: 'fit',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        items: first_tab_form
    }, {
        title: 'My second tab',
        //layout: 'fit',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        items: second_tab_form
    }]
});

var MyWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {           
        height: 560,           
        y: 10,
        width: 800,
        //autoScroll: true,
        //closeAction: 'hide',
        frame: false,
        border: false,
        modal: true,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        plain: true,
        //layout: 'fit',
        maximizable: true,
        items: MyTabs
    }).show();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to 4.1x - these issue due to virtual scrolling have been fixed.